# UIbutton added to subView crashes app swift

Tags: ios, swift

I created a UIButton which I want to add directly to the top of another UIbutton which was created in storyboard. I added the created one programmatically but it crashes the application.

```
var routeButton: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(routeButton)
        setupRouteBtn()
    }

fileprivate func setupRouteBtn() {

        routeButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        routeButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.flatBlack()
        routeButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        routeButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        routeButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

        //        routeBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        //        routeBtn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

        routeButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fab.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        routeButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fab.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        routeButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fab.topAnchor).isActive = true

        routeButton.setNeedsLayout()
        routeButton.layoutIfNeeded()
        routeButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * routeButton.bounds.size.width
        routeButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"Group-3.png"), for: .normal)
        routeButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        routeButton.clipsToBounds = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `routeButton` variable is `nil` when you're adding it as subview. You need to assign it **before** you add it as subview

```
var routeButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
```

... then don't assign it in `setupRouteBtn`

<strike>`routeButton = UIButton(type: .custom)`</strike>

---

```
var routeButton = UIButton(type: .custom)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(routeButton)
    setupRouteBtn()
}

fileprivate func setupRouteBtn() {
    routeButton.backgroundColor = .flatBlack()
    ...
}
```